# how to add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi all i have a problem with UISwipeGestureRecognizer to web view i am using below code to add swipe recognizer but its not working .how can solve this problem please help me

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *DownRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(DownSwipeHandle:)];
    DownRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [DownRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:DownRecognizer];//even if i use not working[_webview addGestureRecognizer:DownRecognizer];
    DownRecognizer.delegate=self;
    [DownRecognizer release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use this method it will be work.

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```